# Flutter Bluetooth Permissions Issue on Android 13: Unable to Scan for Devices

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I am developing a Flutter app that utilizes Bluetooth functionality, specifically Bluetooth scanning, using the flutter_blue package. I have encountered an issue related to Bluetooth permissions on Android 13.

Problem Description:

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I have included the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

In my Flutter code, I am using the `permission_handler` package to request Bluetooth scanning and location permissions. Here's my code snippet:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  requestBluetoothPermission();
}

void requestBluetoothPermission() async {
  PermissionStatus bluetoothStatus = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
  PermissionStatus locationStatus = await Permission.location.request();

  if (bluetoothStatus.isGranted && locationStatus.isGranted) {
    scanDevices();
  } else {  }
```

}

```
void scanDevices() {
  try {
    flutterBlue.startScan();
    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      setState(() {
        _scannedDevices = results;
        print("Bluetooth scan results: ${results.toString()}");
      });
    });
  } catch(e) {
    print("Error during Bluetooth scanning: $e");
  }
}
```

Issue: Despite requesting the necessary permissions, I am still encountering the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled     
Exception:PlatformException(startScan, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN 
permission for     AttributionSource { uid = XXXX, packageName = XXXX, attributionTag 
= null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@XXXX, next = null }: GattService 
registerScanner, java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN 
permission for AttributionSource { uid = XXXX, packageName = XXXX, attributionTag = 
null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@XXXX, next = null }: GattService registerScanner
Additional Information:
```

Flutter version: 3.13.2
flutter_blue package version: 0.8.0
permission_handler package version: 11.0.0
Android version: 13

I have already checked the permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file and ensured that I am requesting them correctly in my Flutter code. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully scan for Bluetooth devices on Android 13?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions), you have to include `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission in order to be able to scan Bluetooth devices.

> If your app looks for Bluetooth devices, such as BLE peripherals, declare the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission.

So in your manifest it should look like this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
```

Comment: it solved, tnx
but there is one more permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>`